# Grabbing Multiple Photo Albums from Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, nsarray, nsdictionary

I've been trying to access the pictures in photo album of facebook. I managed to enter and get the information, but when it comes to storing it into the placesArray, i only store the last album that i grabbed from facebook. I want to grab all the normal albums, and currently i have 2, but i only can grab 1. this is my code

```
 NSString *get_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/albums", valueID];
        FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response2 = [fbGraph doGraphGet:get_string withGetVars:nil];


    //parse our json
    SBJSON *parser2 = [[SBJSON alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *facebook_response2 = [parser2 objectWithString:fb_graph_response2.htmlResponse error:nil];    
    [parser2 release];


    NSMutableArray *photoAlbums = (NSMutableArray *) [facebook_response2 objectForKey:@"data"];


    int index;
    int i;

    placesArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (index=0; index<[photoAlbums count]; index++) 
    {

        NSString* forTable=[photoAlbums objectAtIndex:index];

        NSString *tempString = [forTable valueForKey:@"type"];
        NSLog(@"--------%@",tempString);

        if([tempString isEqualToString:@"normal"]){

            NSLog(@"do something with albums");
            NSLog(@"Count of photo albums : %i",photoAlbums.count);

            placeId = [forTable valueForKey:@"id"];
            currentAlbumID = placeId; 
            name = [forTable valueForKey:@"name"];
            description = [forTable valueForKey:@"description"];
            address = [forTable valueForKey:@"location"];
            updatedTime = [forTable valueForKey:@"updated_time"];            

            [self getMePicturesInThePhotoAlbums];


            NSLog(@"\n Place ID --->>  %@", placeId);
            NSLog(@"\n Place Name -->>  %@", name);
            NSLog(@"\n Place Description -->>  %@", description);
            NSLog(@"\n Place Address -->>  %@", address);
            NSLog(@"\n Place Updated Time -->>  %@", updatedTime);

            NSLog(@"\n Place latX --->>  %@", latX);
            NSLog(@"\n Place latY -->>  %@", latY);
            NSLog(@"\n Place contact -->>  %@", contact);
            NSLog(@"\n Place image1 -->>  %@", image1);
            NSLog(@"\n Place image2 -->>  %@", image2);
            NSLog(@"\n Place image3 --->>  %@", image3);
            NSLog(@"\n Place menuArrayImage -->>  %@", menuArrayImage);


            //------------------------------------------------------------------------





            //------------------------------------------------------------------------

            i = index;

            if(i < [photoAlbums count])
            {

            dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                   placeId, @"placeId",
                   name, @"name",
                   description, @"description",
                   address, @"address",
                   updatedTime, @"updatedTime",
                   latX, @"latX",
                   latY, @"latY",
                   contact, @"contact",
                   image1, @"image1",
                   image2, @"image2",
                   image3, @"image3",
                   menuArrayImage, @"menuArrayImage",
                    nil];

                  [placesArray addObject: dic];


            }

    NSLog(@"%d",[placesArray count]);
    NSInteger bil;

    bil = [placesArray count];

    NSLog(@"BIL >> %i", bil);
    for(int i =0 ; i < bil ; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"\nelement %d is :%@",i,[placesArray objectAtIndex:i]);
    }


}
```